# BLE Peripheral not displaying correctly

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am currently having some issues with connecting to my peripheral. The bluetooth module in our peripheral does not seem to be advertising a name initially. I've have found that once I connect to the peripheral for the first time it will update the name and my scanner is then able to see the correct name.

I have no understanding why this is the case. I have also tried it using the Swift app we are developing, as well as a range of Bluetooth scanners on iOS and Android so I do not believe that this is an OS or programming error on the scanner side.

Is there a specific parameter that should be set on the peripheral. As I am just the app developer I do not have very much understanding about how the module is handing the process.

Any help would be much appreciated.

*Just to confirm the scanner does not see a name for the peripheral until it has connected once. After this it will start displaying the name. Once the peripherals name is changed the old name is still being displayed until I have connected to it once again.*

Comment: You can check with LightBlue.app (I'm not the developper, it's just a good debug app on the AppStore). See if you see it. Else, you might not be advertising it, and since advertisement data comes into chunk, check (with the correct scanning options), it appears various times, and once with its name.

Comment: The name can both be included in the GATT name characteristic and in the advertising data. You could extract the name field from the advertising data to make sure you get the correct one.

Comment: I know that the device is advertising because when using the app "Bluetooth BLE Device Finder" app from the AppStore which automatically tries to connect to all peripheral the name is being updated. Therefore I know it is being advertised and only updates the name upon initial connection.

Answer (score 0):

To display the name of device you need to see in **advertisementData** Dictionary which contains several keys depending on your device, in callback of didDiscoverPeripheral from CentralManager.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

You can look for key **CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey**.

If you do not see the name, you can make changes in your firmware to include a name in GATT characteristic .

You can use LightBlue app to verify once. This is a good app on app-store to test your BLE device.